# Como alterar a cor da borda de um TextFormField?

Tags: material-design, dart, flutter

Gostaria de alterar a cor da borda do TextFormField na tela de login para branco, porque o fundo está gradiente e ficaria mais fácil de visualizar o texto.
Hoje estou utilizando o padrão que criei para o tema:

```
ThemeData buildTheme() {
  final ThemeData base = ThemeData();

  return base.copyWith(
    primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue,
    inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    ),
  );
}
```

E tentei criar uma `decoration` no campo:

```
final password = TextFormField(
  autofocus: false,
  obscureText: true,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Senha',
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    )
  ),
);
```

Mas não obtive sucesso. Como posso fazer isso apenas para os campos dessa tela?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver este problema criei um novo tema para o `TextFormField` em questão:

```
final password = new Theme(
  data: new ThemeData(
    hintColor: Colors.white,
  ),
  child: TextFormField(
    autofocus: false,
    obscureText: true,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: 'Senha',
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

ou voce pode desativar a borda simplesmente usando enabledBorder: InputBorder.none dentro do InputDecoration ex:

```
TextFormField(
 decoration: InputDecoration(
 labelText: 'Email',
 enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,// isso que vc quer para desativar a borda
 labelStyle: TextStyle(
 color: Colors.white,
 fontSize: 15.0,
  ),
 ),
),
```

Answer (score -1):

Você tem que fazer pelo `Main.dart`

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Dog Life',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
        
      ),
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}
```